# Intuition behind Kleene's “second algebra” $\mathcal{K}_2$

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, big-picture, computable-analysis

The “second Kleene algebra” $\mathcal{K}_2$ is defined, e.g. [here on nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kleene%27s+second+algebra), or in section 1.4.3 of van Oosten's book *Realizability: an Introduction to its Categorical Side* (2008), or as example 3.4 of [the notes “Realizability” by Thomas Streicher (2017–2018)](https://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/%7Estreicher/REAL/REAL.pdf), or (implicitly) in ¶1.9.12 of Troelstra's *Metamathematical Investigations of Intuitionistic Arithmetic and Analysis* (1973), or in various other places.  Let me reproduce the essential part of the definition for readers' convenience:

> Let $\mathcal{B} = \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ denote Baire space, endowed with its usual product topology.  Given $\alpha \in \mathcal{B}$, define $F_\alpha$ a partial function from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ by
> $$
> F_\alpha(\beta) = n\quad\text{iff}\quad\exists k\in\mathbb{N}.(\alpha(\bar\beta\upharpoonright k)=n+1 \land \forall \ell<k.(\alpha(\bar\beta\upharpoonright k)=0))
> $$
> (undefined if no such $n$ exists) where $\bar\beta \upharpoonright k$ denotes an integer encoding the finite sequence $\langle\beta(0),\ldots,\beta(k-1)\rangle$.  This defines a continuous function $U \to \mathbb{N}$ with $U \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ open, and any such function is of the form in question.
>
> Now let
> $$
> \alpha\bullet\beta = (n \mapsto F_\alpha(\langle n\rangle \smallfrown \beta))
> $$
> provided $F_\alpha(\langle n\rangle \smallfrown \beta)$ is defined for every $n$, undefined otherwise, where $\langle n\rangle \smallfrown \beta$ denotes the function $0 \mapsto n$ and $k+1 \mapsto \beta(k)$.  Then $\mathcal{K}_2$ is $\mathcal{B}$ endowed with this partial operation $\bullet$.

This definition is not complicated, but it is… extremely opaque, and none of the sources I've cited bother to explain why we define things in this particular way ($F_\alpha(\beta)$ searches for the first nonzero value among the values returned by $\alpha$ on the finite subsequences of $\beta$ and subtracts one to it: why do we want to do precisely this? rather than, say, return the index $k$ where this nonzero value was found), apart from the fact that “it works” (it gives a partial combinatory algebra).

Kleene's *first* algebra $\mathcal{K}_1$ (namely $\mathbb{N}$ with the operation $e\bullet n = \varphi_e(n)$ for some standard enumeration $\varphi$ of partial recursive functions) is easy to develop an intuition for: it's the set of computable functions, i.e., computer programs, and the operation is that of taking data and feeding it to a computer program.  I understand that the idea behind $\mathcal{K}_2$ is to do something similar for continuous functions on Baire space (and that $F_\alpha$ must play a role analogous to $\varphi_e$), but this doesn't really help me explain the particulars of the definition above (I feel like if in the case of $\mathcal{K}_1$ I'd been described what a Turing machine was without any explanation as to how this definition was reached).  So:

**Question:** What's the intuition behind the definition of $\mathcal{K}_2$ and the reason for this particular choice of definition?  Has anyone written an introduction to $\mathcal{K}_2$ analogous to what a first course on computability theory would be on $\mathcal{K}_1$?

Comment: A fairly paedagogical explanation is found in [Andrej Bauer's notes on realizability](https://www.andrej.com/zapiski/MGS-2022/notes-on-realizability.pdf), in the chapter titled “models of computation”, esp. the subsection “type-2 machines”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bit of explanation in my [lecture notes on intuitionistic logic](https://awswan.github.io/teaching/intuitionisticlogic/index.html), in particular the [section on function realizability](https://awswan.github.io/teaching/intuitionisticlogic/lecturenotes/section14.pdf).

The idea is that you want to encode continuous partial functions $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ as elements of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ analogously to how computable partial functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ can be encoded as elements of $\mathbb{N}$. It turns out the main idea comes up just encoding partial continuous functions $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, so I'll talk about that.

It's easiest to break it into two steps. Write $\mathbb{N}^{< \omega}$ for finite sequences of numbers. Then given a function $f : \mathbb{N}^{< \omega} \to \mathbb{N} + \{\bot\}$, we can view it as a continuous partial function $F : \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ as follows. To compute $F(g)$ we feed finite approximations of $g$, e.g. the length $k$ approximation $[g(0), g(1), g(2), \ldots, g(k)]$. $f([g(0), g(1), g(2), \ldots, g(k)])$ can either lie in the $\mathbb{N}$ component of $\mathbb{N} + \{\bot\}$ or it's equal to $\bot$. The former tells us that we can compute the value of $F(g)$ from this list, and it is equal to $f([g(0), \ldots, g(k)])$ (unless it was already computed at an earlier stage). The latter, $f([g(0), \ldots, g(k)]) = \bot$, tells us $f$ has not been given enough information and needs a longer list before it can return a value.

Finally note that $\mathbb{N}^{< \omega}$ and $\mathbb{N} + \{\bot\}$ are both countable, so we can view $f$ as a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. In particular checking for a number $> 0$ and then subtracting $1$ comes from  the bijection $\mathbb{N} + \{\bot\} \cong \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equivalent definition. A realizer is a [type-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis#Type_2_Turing_Machines) turing machine, except that instead of having finitely many states there are $\aleph_0$ many states. This means that the instruction table must be infinite as well.

Given some reasonable encoding function $e$ that encodes such a machine into an infinite string, we define $e(M) \bullet \alpha$ as the result of running $M$ when $\alpha$ is on the input tape.

Here are the required combinators. They are the encoding of these machines:

- $k \bullet \alpha$: The initial state is $0$. When in state $n$, it writes $\alpha(n)$ to the output tape, moves the output head right, and then goes to state $n+1$. The symbol on the input tape is ignored.
- $k$: Writes $e(k \bullet \alpha)$ as described in the previous point to the output tape, where $\alpha$ is on the input tape.
- $(s \bullet \alpha) \bullet \beta$: Does the following three steps in parallel by [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_%28computer_science%29)

  1. Run the machine encoded by $\alpha$, routing the output to an unused subset of the working tape.
  2. Run the machine encoded by $\beta$, routing the output to an unused subset of the working tape.
  3. Run the machine encoded by the result of step 1, but using the result of step 2 in place of the original input tape. If the machine is missing a needed instruction, pause until step 1 produces it. If the machine tries to move the simulated input head to a cell that step 2 has not produced yet, pause until step 2 does so.
- $s \bullet \alpha$: Writes $e((s \bullet \alpha) \bullet \beta)$ as described in the previous point to output, where $\beta$ is on the input tape.
- $s$: Writes $e(s \bullet \alpha)$ as described in the previous point to output, where $\alpha$ is on the input tape.

The last four machines exist via the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding an answer to my own question to point out one thing about Kleene's $\mathcal{K}_2$ which I had previously failed to understand and which is an important difference with $\mathcal{K}_1$ that probably deserves its own special *caveat* in any description of $\mathcal{K}_2$: **in $\mathcal{K}_1$ one can “run programs in parallel”, but apparently one cannot do this in $\mathcal{K}_2$**.

That is, $\mathcal{K}_1$ has the property that given $e_1,e_2$ (in $\mathcal{K}_1$, that is to say, $\mathbb{N}$) there exists $e$ such that that $e\bullet n$ is defined iff either $e_1\bullet n$ or $e_2\bullet n$ is defined, and moreover, when this is the case, $e\bullet n$ equals one of the values $e_1\bullet n$ or $e_2\bullet n$ which is defined (so, the one which is defined if only one is defined).  Furthermore, we can find such $e$ effectively from $e_1,e_2$ (meaning that there is a $p$ such that $(p\bullet e_1)\bullet e_2$ gives such an $e$ as I wrote).  Indeed, we do this by running $e_1$ and $e_2$ in parallel until one produces a result, and returning the result in question (this is a consequence of Kleene's normal form theorem).

This property, however, *does not hold* for $\mathcal{K}_2$: while it *is* true that ① given $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ (in $\mathcal{K}_2$, that is to say, $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$) there exists $\varepsilon$ such that that $\varepsilon\bullet \nu$ is defined iff either $\varepsilon_1\bullet \nu$ or $\varepsilon_2\bullet \nu$ is defined, however we cannot ② add the condition that, $\varepsilon\bullet \nu$ equals one of the values $\varepsilon_1\bullet \nu$ or $\varepsilon_2\bullet \nu$ which is defined, not even if we assume that $\varepsilon_1\bullet \nu$ and $\varepsilon_2\bullet \nu$ are never simultaneously defined.

Indeed, this is obvious topologically: as explained in [Andrej Bauer's notes on realizability](https://www.andrej.com/zapiski/MGS-2022/notes-on-realizability.pdf), theorem 2.1.14, the partial maps $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of the form $\nu \mapsto \varepsilon\bullet\nu$ are precisely the *continuous maps on a $G_\delta$ domain*.  Now $G_\delta$ sets are closed under finite union, so this shows ①; however, given two continuous functions on disjoint $G_\delta$ sets there does not necessarily exist one which extends them on the union (disproving ②).  Indeed, a trivial counterexample is given by the partial function $F_1\colon \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ taking the constant function with value $0$ at the constant function with value $0$ and undefined elsewhere, and the partial function $F_2\colon \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ taking the constant function with value $1$ everywhere except at the constant function with value $0$ and undefined there.  Clearly $F_1$ and $F_2$ are continuous and each defined on a $G_\delta$, but the unique function $F$ extending them to the union of their domains, i.e. to $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, is not continuous, so not realized by an element of $\mathcal{K}_2^{\mathrm{eff}}$.  Moreover, each of $F_1$ and $F_2$ belong to the effective part of $\mathcal{K}_2$ (the one realized by Turing-computable functions in $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$), so this defect(?) of $\mathcal{K}_2$ caries over to $\mathcal{K}_2^{\mathrm{eff}}$.

The difficulty arises from the way we move from functions $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ to functions $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$.  The former have no such problem: the ones described by an element of $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ are precisely the continuous functions on an *open domain*, and we can glue such functions (feed the input function and take the first one that returns a value), but when going to $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ things break apart as the previous counterexample shows.

I don't know if this should be considered a “defect” of $\mathcal{K}_2$, but I urge anyone writing a explanation of $\mathcal{K}_2$ to add a warning to the reader that this property we tend to take for granted in $\mathcal{K}_1$ does not hold for $\mathcal{K}_2$ and it's likely to confuse beginners.

Comment: A similar observation is this: in $\mathcal{K}_1$ the relation "$n \bullet m$ is defined" is semidecidable, but in $\mathcal{K}_2$ the relation "$\alpha \bullet \beta$ is defined" is a $\Pi^0_2$ statement (for every output cell there are initial segments of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that determine its value).